# git workflow misunderstanding

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am trying to implement workflow with the `master` for production and `dev` for development [described here.](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

1. creating branch `dev` from origin

   - `git push --set-upstream origin dev`
2. from the `dev` branch creating ticket branch and switching to it

   - `git checkout -b 1234_short_description`
3. working and committing locally

   - `git commit -am "description of the changes for this commit"`
4. time to push my ticket branch `1234_short_description` to the remote `dev` repository, so the team lead can check what was made and decline or approve and then merge my work into the `dev` branch.

I am trying but the only thing git wants do is create `origin/1234_short_description`.

Please explain to me how to create a branch from the `dev` branch and push to the remote `dev` branch according to the given git flow.

Maybe in that workflow the `dev` branch and `master` both remote repositories but not `dev` branch as said there?

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you to push on the same branch as you are working in local, not in dev otherwise you can simply work on dev branch

When you have push to origin/branch123 you should create a pull request (PR) from this branch to the dev one. Team lead will review the PR and merge it if it's ok. If not you will simply push again on your branch after fixing it.

On bitbucket you can also add reviewers on the PR and create rules like a PR must have been approved by 2 dev to be merge

Comment: yes, but when im trying to push my `1234_short_description`, git trying to create `origin/1234_short_description`, but this supposed to be `dev/1234_short_description`. how to implement described workflow with the `dev` and `master` branches ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check what the configured upstream branch is by doing

```
git branch -vv --list 1234_short_description
```

You can set the upstream branch to dev/1234_short_description for branch 1234_short_description by doing:

```
git branch -u dev/1234_short_description 1234_short_description
```

You can set the default push behaviour to push to the configured upstream branch by doing one of:

```
git config --global push.default simple
git config --global push.default upstream
```

Both of these will cause the default push behaviour to push to the configured upstream branch. "simple" will refuse the push if the remote branch has a different name than the local branch, while "upstream" will always push to the configured upstream branch.

After this, it should be possible to push by simply doing `git push`.

### Alternative approach, with no change to configuraions

You can also specify the full refspec to push. Instead of doing just `git push`, do:

```
git push dev 1234_short_description:1234_short_description
```

Which means "push local branch `1234_short_description` to remote branch `1234_short_description` in `dev` repo.

Comment: could you provide me more details:

`$ git branch -vv`
`dev                          4d46c96 [origin/dev] Merge branch '1783' into dev`
`dev_3_feature         226b914 second commit in dev_3_feature`
`dev_second_feature          6b5f10f second commit in dev_2_feature`
`master                            baf5fc0 [origin/master: ahead 1] master feature`
`* myFeature                         da5cc64 second commit in dev_1_feature`
` test                              334cf7e commiting my super changes locally`

i want my DEV features to be pushed into `origin/dev` how can i do that ?